# Preload vs. Database Cascading Dropdown Lists

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, linux, apache

I'm new to web development and for my first project I have a need for 4 cascading drop down menus. Ive been reading as much as I can about the best way to tackle this and there is some discussion about whether to preload these lists or to grab them from my database. Mine is a LAMP project and I have about 5000 items that need to go into these dropdown menus. The discussion I've seen states that if you don't have a large number of dropdown items you are much better off preloading these items and pulling them using javascript. My question is what is considered a large number? With 5000 items am I much better off going the MySQL route? On some level I prefer that but all of the tutorials out there seem to deal with either ASP or preloaded items. So my questions are:

Is 5000 items too many to preload for a dropdown list? What would the cutoff be?

And, do you know of any good tutorials to get me started if MySQL is the way to go. I've seen a couple but they are not very detailed and for a newbie I'm getting wrapped around the axle. Thanks so much!

Comment: IMHO, 5000 is just a huge number for a dropdown in itself. Who'll be the lucky one that will have to select a list of 5K items? (or 4 with 1,250 each) o_O

Comment: 5000 is way too many for a drop down. Personally I'd call that unusable. Preloaded or not, to make that usuable, you'd already have to know something about which you wanted to select, like it started with A or it was Fred's.

Comment: he said 4 cascading dropdowns, like ford > truck > v8 > green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look more to the size in kb than how many items. I'm guessing even 5k entries is going to be 1-2kb after gzip, which is generally very little compared to the rest of the external objects a typical webpage loads(compare to the size of images + css + js).

Having to do multiple separate http requests is expensive from a responsiveness standpoint, especially for high latency connections like mobile devices(web autocomplete is generally pretty lame on my phone due to latency).

So anyway, personally I lean heavily towards just loading it all upfront unless the amount of data gets huge, or the chance of the data being used at all is very low.

Answer (score 0):

First off, 5K in dropdowns, no way! Same for caching it in JS. My advice would be, try to investigate PHP, AJAX and MySQL. Then create an autocomplete system that allows for a non-mindblowing method to access the information.

If you still need a good tutorial or PHP MySQL dropdowns:
http://www.yourwebskills.com/mysqldropdown.php

And then for my advice:

http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/jquery-php-mysql-ajax-autocomplete/
http://www.webinone.net/tutorials/php/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery-and-mysql/

Please read around, and if you can't figure stuff out, please come back and ask!